# How to display google map in Iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, iframe

I want to display google maps in Razor MVC page but its not displaying and getting an error as follows:

Refused to display 'https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ll=XXXXXXXXXX&spn=XXXXXXXXXX&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

The code is as follows:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 251px; height: 202px;">
  <iframe id="iGmap" width="251" height="202" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;ll=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;spn=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;output=embed">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps blocks external sites from embedding it in an iframe. This is a policy on their end, so it's not something you can circumvent. If you want to display the map in an iframe, you'll need to do so via the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) (or one of their other APIs) instead.

Comment: Ok..So is there not any alternative to this?
<iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&sll=19.056545,72.853394&sspn=0.010121,0.021136&ie=UTF8&z=10&ll=19.075984,72.877656&output=embed"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

This I have achieved by removing 'ms?' from my URL

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;ll=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;spn=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;output=embed
```

to

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;ll=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;spn=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;output=embed
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1-VlXsvMWMr8EotfMcIwYKt-1SrI" width="320" height="350" style="margin-top:-387px"></iframe>
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

**All Maps Embed API requests are available at no charge with unlimited usage.**

To create an embedded map on your web page, you should complete the required setup steps in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/quickstart#before_you_begin) first.

If your done with the first step, You now can set the Maps Embed API URL as the src attribute of an iframe like this:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  style="border:0"
  loading="lazy"
  allowfullscreen
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
  &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
</iframe>
```

Hope this helps.